# JaxB - how to not map a specific XML node

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, code-generation

Here is my problem:

I'm working on a project to migrate from Castor to JaxB. I am very new to JaxB and facing a problem which boggles my mind and yet, may be quite simple to solve. Here is a simple example :

```
class Data
{
    private Item item;
}
```

I have Data containing one Item. Here is how the output XML file (**which I cannot change**) looks like:

```
<Data>
    <Items>
        <Item>
        <Item>
    <Items>
<Data>
```

Even though Data contains only one Item, it should be presented in the output XML as an element in Items. The thing is, I do not want JaxB to generate a class or property for Items, only **Data** and **Item**.

How should my schema look like? Is there any way to specify in the schema that the specified item is stored in a node which has no class representation? Something which in my logic could look like that:

```
  <xs:element name="Data">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="Items"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="Items"> <!-- Do not generate plz -->
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="Item" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

For the following fragment, there isn't a way to generate the classes in that way, because the standard JAXB APIs don't provide path based mapping.

```
  <xs:element name="Items"> <!-- Do not generate plz -->
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="Item" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

However, starting from Java classes you could use MOXy's `@XmlPath` extension to map this use case:

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.oxm.XmlPath;

class Data
{
    @XmlPath("Items/Item")
    private Item item;
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: This helped me choose another solution, since it was decided that the classes could not be changed (we discovered some xml files directly unmarshalled into hibernate objects), I began to use MOXy's external metadata mapping.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to write your own jaxb plugin: you can find an introduction here: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2005/06/writing_a_plugi.html. Within your plugin, you generate code using the Codemodel API; I've blogged about that here: http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/weblogs?blog=/pub/wlg/21495. When XJC gets to your "Items" element, it will pass control to you and in your plugin, you'd simply ignore it and create the setter/getter for the underlying "Item" element instead.  I'm sure there are other variations that are just as valid.

Answer (score 0):

Using standard JAXB annotations:

```
class Data{
  @XmlElementWrapper(name="Items")
  @XmlElement(name="Item")
  private Item[] item;     // An array with just one Item
}
```